# Ошибка в коде при создании функции с помощью foreach

Tags: php

Мне нужно понять, где моя ошибка.

Вот задача: Реализуйте функцию `isContinuousSequence`, которая проверяет, является ли переданная последовательность целых чисел - возрастающей непрерывно (не имеющей пропусков чисел).

```
<?php

namespace App\Arrays;

// BEGIN (write your solution here)

function isContinuousSequence($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
        if ($value[$index] + 1 == $value[$index + 1]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вот это `$value[$index + 1]` вызовет ошибку на последнем элементе. Или используйте for до предпоследнего или контролируйте, что это последний индекс

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)